# Catching Polygons on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, polygon

I'm trying to make a map editor that supports rectangles in different angles (so it draws rectangles using polygons). I want to catch a polygon by their location on the frame without using mathematical calculations.

Is there a command supports such thing?

I tried to catch polygons by their visual representations:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
 Component component = getComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
  if(component instanceof wall){
```

but it doesn't work.

(If i was simply drawing rectangles i would use JPanel and use setbounds command to draw a rectangle, but i dont think i can make polygon-shaped JPanels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a List containing all the Polygons you want to paint:

```
Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 30);
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapes.add( circle );
```

Then in your paintComponent() method you iterate through all the shapes in the List:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

for (Shape shape : shapes)
{
    g2d.draw( shape );
}

g2d.dispose();
```

Then in the MouseListener you iterate through the List to see which Shape was clicked:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    for (Shape shape : shapes)
    {
        if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())
            // do something
    }

}
```

> If i was simply drawing rectangles i would use JPanel and use setbounds command to draw a rectangle, but i dont think i can make polygon-shaped JPanels

For an alternative approach that does use a component check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). The classes there allow you to create a `ShapeComponent` by using any Shape.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, i now alot more about how the shapes work and hopefully i will get my code working with your aid :)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use individual JPanels to draw each Polygon. You would use a single class that extends JPanel, then overrides the paintComponent() method to draw the Polygons. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Once you've drawn your Polygons to the JPanel, you can use the Polygon.contains() method to test whether the mouse was inside a JPanel. More info on that in [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer good sir, although camickr's answer seems to be the "proper way" of doing what i want to do, the way you suggested is going to be much easier to implement, so i will go with this one :)

Comment: @Eren Camickr and I are proposing the same solution.

Comment: Oooh so Polygons.contains method is same as Shape.contains method, i see, thank you. I tought Polygons.contains method was specific code for Polygon api  BTW is there a noticable differance between paint component and paint , because im using paint

Comment: @Eren You should use paintComponent. The tutorial I linked explains why, but basically the paint() method handles stuff like double buffering for you, so you shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: Thank you, i will check the tutorial in future date as im going to bed right now, but i wanted to tell you that i managed to get the code working many thanks to you and camickr.